# SessionNotCreatedException from chromedriver on java selenium project

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, testng

I am getting SessionNotCreatedException from chromedriver on java selenium project. I am also using TestNG and all this running on Linux mint.

Here are my chrome options:

```
 static ChromeOptions getLocalChromeOptions() {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");
    options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
    options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", getChromeExperimentalOptions(LOCAL_DOWNLOADS_FOLDER));

    return options;
}
```

and the exception itself

```
    org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '4.1.1', revision: 'e8fcc2cecf'
System info: host: 'username-pc', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-131-generic', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--ignore-ssl-errors=yes, --ignore-certificate-errors, --disable-popup-blocking, --start-maximized], extensions: [], prefs: {download.default_directory: /home/usernam/Downloads, download.directory_upgrade: true, download.prompt_for_download: false, plugins.always_open_pdf_externally: true, plugins.plugins_disabled: [Chrome PDF Viewer], profile.default_content_settings.popups: 0, safebrowsing.enabled: false}}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--ignore-ssl-errors=yes, --ignore-certificate-errors, --disable-popup-blocking, --start-maximized], extensions: [], prefs: {download.default_directory: /home/username/Downloads, download.directory_upgrade: true, download.prompt_for_download: false, plugins.always_open_pdf_externally: true, plugins.plugins_disabled: [Chrome PDF Viewer], profile.default_content_settings.popups: 0, safebrowsing.enabled: false}}}}]

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:230)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:151)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:80)
    at com.company.platform.selenium.managers.ChromeDriverManager.createDriver(ChromeDriverManager.java:12)
    at com.company.platform.tests.BaseTest.setUp(BaseTest.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:700)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:527)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
```

I moved the driver from the location "/usr/bin/google-chrome", but even when it was there, I had this issue. The irony is that everything operates normally on a virtual machine on the same pc.

Comment: Look at chromedriver log

Answer (score 0):

Following my old tradition, I solved it by myself soon after I posted here. And here is what happened:
Selenium was looking for the file google-chrome which is basically a link to /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome, but it turned out that I only have google-chrome-stable, which selenium does not recognize. So using the following command inside the /usr/bin directory

```
sudo ln -s /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome google-chrome
```

I created another shortcut to the same location, but this time with the name google-chrome. After that everything works as charm.
I hope this will come in handy for someone else too.
Peace!